# Is it ok to have an @ sign in the query portion of a url?

Tags: url, browser, uri

A server I'm working on has email addresses as part of a query in a URL that users can click on. Right now, the `@` sign is encoded as an `@` sign in the urls, and this works totally fine. I thought it would break things and that I would need to change this to a `%40`, but that doesn't seem to be the case (from my experience). Since I don't have access to countless different configurations and browsers, I figured I would check here to see whether or not this will be a problem elsewhere.

Anybody more knowledgeable than me wanna chime in?

Sami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you get by without encoding it?  Probably.  I believe the @ (at sign) is only used when building out an FTP URL (e.g. ftp://user:password@host:port).  I would still encode it because the @ sign is a reserved character according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).

Comment: Actually, that syntax is used by HTTP too.  However, it only appears before the hostname.

Comment: @SLaks - Could you provide an example?

Comment: That's how certain organizations send their AD passwords plain-text across the network.